# How can I break line on Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I tried break line using `\n`, `putStrLn` and `print` but nothing works.

When I use `\n` the result only concatenates the strings, and when I use `putStrLn` or `print` I receive a type error.

**Output for `\n`:**

```
formatLines [("a",12),("b",13),("c",14)]
"a...............12\nb...............13\nc...............14\n"
```

**Output for `putStrLn`:**

```
format.hs:6:22:
    Couldn't match type `IO ()' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: IO ()
    In the return type of a call of `putStrLn'
    In the expression:
      putStrLn (formatLine ((fst x), (snd x)) ++ formatLines xs)
    In an equation for `formatLines':
        formatLines (x : xs)
          = putStrLn (formatLine ((fst x), (snd x)) ++ formatLines xs)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

the output for `print` is the same as that of `putStrLn`

Here is my code:

```
formatLine :: (String,Integer) -> String
formatLine (s, i) = s ++ "..............." ++ show i

formatLines::[(String,Integer)] -> String
formatLines [] = ""
formatLines (x:xs) = print (formatLine ((fst x), (snd x)) ++ formatLines xs)
```

I understand the reason of the error for `print` and `putStrLn` but i have no idea how fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Split your code in two parts.

One part simply constructs the string. Use `"\n"` for newlines.

The second part takes the string and applies `putStrLn` (NOT `print`) to it. The newlines will get printed correctly.

Example:

```
foo :: String -> Int -> String
foo s n = s ++ "\n" ++ show (n*10) ++ "\n" ++ s

bar :: IO ()
bar = putStrLn (foo "abc" 42)
    -- or putStr (...) for no trailing newline

baz :: String -> IO ()
baz s = putStrLn (foo s 21)
```

If you use `print` instead, you'll print the string representation, with quotes and escapes (like `\n`) inside it. Use `print` only for values that have to be converted to string, like numbers.

Also note that you can only do IO (like printing stuff) in functions whose return type is `IO (something)`.

Comment: I didn't understand completely. The return of bar is a IO () and doesn't have a input , but if I wish pass a parameter to the bar function? Because I need specify the input. For example  `bar s i = putStrLn (foo s i)` ?

Comment: @Marcio You can add additional arguments. The `bar` in your example will have type `bar :: String -> Int -> IO ()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I have more one doubt: exists some way to concatenate the result of bar with a String? I'm trying with `show`, doing something like this: `"hello" ++ (show baz s)` but didn't work. Appear a message "No instance for (Show (IO ())) arising from a use of `show'" and I don't know what could be a instance of show. I'm sorry if I'm taking advantage of you

Comment: @Marcio That makes no sense. `baz` does not return a string, it returns an IO action. I.e. `baz` prints the string, it does not return it. If you want to further concatenate, use the pure `foo` function e.g. `"hello" ++ foo "a" 2` -- no need to `show` here.

Comment: I suggest that you read about the difference between returning a String and printing a value to the screen. You sold also learn more about `IO()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the results to output.

This is an IO action, and so you cannot have a function signature ending with `-> String`. Instead, as @chi points out, the return type should be `IO ()`. Further, since you have the function to generate formatted string already, all you need is a function to help you map the printing action over your input list. This you can do using `mapM_`, like so:

```
formatLines::[(String,Integer)] -> IO ()
formatLines y = mapM_ (putStrLn . formatLine) y
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/MTHJA50026)